forward fill or back fill nil values in a swift DataFrame
Looking for a way to forward fill or back fill nil values in a swift DataFrame. I've figured out a way to do it for forward filling one nil value but not for multiple in a row. I don't think swift has this function built in?
This is the solution I came up with for one nil value forward filling:
var pre: Double? = nil
dataframe.transformColumn("columnName") { (thisElement:Double?) in
    if let thisElement {
        pre = thisElement
        return thisElement
    }
    return pre
}


You should get a typed column, Column<T>. This is a mutable and bidirectional collection, so you can iterate in whichever direction you want.
extension Column {
    mutating func backfill() {
        var prev: Element = nil
        for i in self.indices.reversed() {
            if self[i] != nil {
                prev = self[i]
            } else {
                self[i] = prev
            }
        }
    }
    
    mutating func forwardFill() {
        var prev: Element = nil
        for i in self.indices {
            if self[i] != nil {
                prev = self[i]
            } else {
                self[i] = prev
            }
        }
    }
}

Usage:
var df: DataFrame = ["Foo": [1, 2, nil, 3]]
df["Foo", Int.self].backfill()
print(df)

